# Treat NA as 0 in custom function for lapp in {terra} R library

Tags: r, spatial-statistics, code-review, terra, rstats

I am trying to use the lapp function from the terra rstats library to do some raster-math. But when cells have NA in them, it is giving me the 'wrong' result. Here is my current function and result.

```
a <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(1,1,1,1))
b <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(1,1,1,NA))
c <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(1,NA,1,1))

original_function <- function(a, b, c) {
                            d <- a + (b - c)
                            return(d)}

result <- lapp(sds(a,b,c),
                original_function)

values(result)

     lyr.1
[1,]     1
[2,]    NA
[3,]     1
[4,]    NA
```

I get some NAs in the result. I would rather NAs in the input rasters are treated as 0s. Here is an attempt at doing this and the result.

```
a <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(1,1,1,1))
b <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(1,1,1,NA))
c <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(1,NA,1,1))

vectorised_function <-  function(a, b, c) {
                            a[is.na(a)] <- 0
                            b[is.na(b)] <- 0
                            c[is.na(c)] <- 0
                            d <- a + (b - c)
                            return(d)}

result <- lapp(sds(a,b,c),
                vectorised_function)

values(result)

     lyr.1
[1,]     1
[2,]     2
[3,]     1
[4,]     0
```

The result is now 'correct' for my purposes but is this a silly way to approach this?

I am going to be working with 5GB+ input rasters so performance is also a concern.

Comment: You've got `d <- b + (b - c)` which I think should be `d <- a + (b - c)` - I'd edit it but it does change the outputs so I'll leave it to you to edit and re-run if its necessary!

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman . Fixed and re-ran.

Comment: If you are working with rasters that are too big to be in-memory and your calculation isn't that complicated then `gdal_calc.py` from the suite of gdal command line tools might be faster?

Comment: lapp is memory safe, so I think it should be fine. Kind of keen to stay with the suite of tools I'm currently using. I tried to use gdal_calc.py a few months ago and found the formula syntax very tricky.

Comment: An alternative using `ifelse(is.na(a[]), 0, a[])` etc to replace NA with 0 worked out slower from benchmarking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is much the same as this one but this is perhaps a bit more concise...

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.5.49

a <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(1,1,1,1))
b <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(1,1,1,NA))
c <- rast(ncol = 2, nrow = 2, vals = c(1,NA,1,1))


#option 2 -  with lapp
result <- lapply(list(a,b,c), function(x) {x[is.na(x)] <-0; x}) |>
  sds() |>
  lapp(function(x,y,z) x + (y-z)) 

values(result)
#>      lyr.1
#> [1,]     1
#> [2,]     2
#> [3,]     1
#> [4,]     0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>